# What are the top 5 deployment automation tools?

Tags: deployment, automation

I am using IBM UrbanCode udeploy, great tool but afraid IBM will kill it sooner or later with their slow response in supporting. What are the other choices?

Answer (score 0):

UCD isn't going anywhere. Its in high demand these days, and is gaining traction in z/OS shops as well.

However, there other popular tools are Chef and Puppet. Just be prepared for manual data entry and less friendly interface. They work, but are more work to use.